# VBA to Combine 2 csv files, and add what is missing

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to combine 2 files into 1 using VBA. Most of the text is the same in each, but some have a little extra that needs to be saved. How do I go through each row of 2 CSV files and compare and add the original and what's different and separate each with a * just so I know the separation onto a 3rd CSV[image] file?

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off doing this in Word using "compare documents".  That doesn't really look like a job for Excel, without reinventing a bunch of wheels.

Comment: I think you could also use the Inquire add-in, which comes prepackaged with Excel and can compare two files.